# Jail-Chrooted OpenVPN Service with Apparmor fails with Operation not permitted

Tags: linux, debian, openvpn, apparmor

I have an OpenVPN client with chroot-jail currently working as a Linux service `openvpn-client@vpn`

I am trying to make it work with AppArmor, I created the OpenVPN profile in /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.openvpn but I am getting this error when the openvpn service attempts to start:

**

> chroot to '/.vpn-jail/' failed: Operation not permitted

**

Without AppArmor the Jail-Chrooted OpenvVPN client service works as needed.

This is my current AppArmor profile for the OpenVPN, I have tried to use flags: chroot_attach, chroot_relative, namespace_relative, etc... but so far I have not been able to make it work.

```
# vim:syntax=apparmor

#include <tunables/global>
#include if exists <tunables/chroot>

profile openvpn /usr/sbin/openvpn flags=(chroot_attach) {
  #include <abstractions/base>
  #include <abstractions/openssl>
  #include <abstractions/nameservice>   # embedded, but more relaxed

  capability net_admin,
  capability setuid,
  capability setgid,

  /etc/openvpn/client/*.conf                    r, # any.conf
  /etc/openvpn/client/credentials/decrypted_credentials.txt r,
  @{VPNCHROOT}/etc/openvpn/client/*.conf    r,
  @{VPNCHROOT}/etc/openvpn/client/credentials/decrypted_credentials.txt    r,

  /dev/net/tun rw,

  @{PROC}/@{pid}/net/route r,

  /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status.log           rw,
  /var/log/openvpn/openvpn.log                  rw,
  /var/log/openvpn/ipp.txt                      rw,
  /{,var/}run/openvpn/server.pid                rw,
  /{,var/}run/openvpn/client{,-*}.pid           rw,
  /{,var/}run/openvpn/client{,-*}.status        rw,

  /{,usr/}bin/ip Cx,
  profile ip /{,usr/}bin/ip {
    /{,usr/}bin/ip r,
    #include <abstractions/base>

    capability net_admin,

    /var/log/openvpn/openvpn.log w,
  }

#  #include <local/usr.sbin.openvpn>
}
```

Comment: 1) Please don't post text as images. 2) `grep apparmor /var/log/syslog`.

Comment: Can you replace the image as text so an answer can be worked on the actual text content?

Comment: just fixed... thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`capabilities(7)`](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/capabilities.7#CAP_SYS_CHROOT) tells:

> `CAP_SYS_CHROOT`
>
> - Use `chroot(2)`;
> - change mount namespaces using `setns(2)`.

None of the other allowed capabilities in the Apparmor configuration grant the privilege to use `chroot(2)`): `chroot()` gets an `EPERM` / *Operation not permitted*.

You'll have to add:

```
capability sys_chroot,
```

in the Apparmor setup. This could become an iterative process: proceed, encounter the next error, check both the application logs and Apparmor logs (usually `/var/log/audit/` and the possible help of a parser) , fix it the same by checking the manual for `capabilities(7)` (or any other limitation rather than a capability), until you get it completely functional.